# ImageIcon Updating for Hangman GUI Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

For my group project we are doing a fairly standard Hangman GUI game.

I have created a series of .png files depicting a flower that wilts as the game progresses with wrong guesses.

I have got the code to insert the ImageIcon into a JLabel, and that works fine. But I don't know how to code for the image changing when a wrong answer is guessed.

I am thinking I should create an array of the series of images and iterate through it according to the guessesLeft variable that keeps track of the number of guesses a user still has to correctly guess the puzzle.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should create a List or array of the images, and iterate through it according to the guessesLeft variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to link each image to the number of guesses.
Then make method `updateScore` that will update user score (or guesses left) and work with images. Something like:

```
public class ImagedScore {
    private final int guessesLeft;
    private final Image image;
    //getters&constructor
}

public class MainClass {
    ImagedScore[] imagedScoreArray;
    //constructors, other methods and data, etc.

    updateScore(int score) {
        ImagedScore imagedScore = imagedScoreArray[score];
        //checks or other way to find proper ImagedScore object
        this.score = score;
        this.image = imagedScore.getImage;
    }
}
```